# How to express the given disk $D$ in polar coordinates.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

> Given $D=\{(x,y)|0\le x\le2,0\le y\le\sqrt{4-x^2}\}$
>
> Express $D$ in polar coordinates.

I have the answer as $D=\{(r,\theta)|0\le\theta\le\dfrac{\pi}{2},0\le r\le2\}$

One more example is

> $D=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\le4\text{ and }y\ge-x\}$

I have the answer as $D=\{(r,\theta)|-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\le\theta\le\dfrac{3\pi}{4},0\le r\le2\}$

**My question is how did they get the coordinates as** $0\le\theta\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\le\theta\le\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$

Can anyone please explain me how to get those coordinates.

Comment: You have $0 \leq x \leq 0$ in the first example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will update the answer for to include the first example when you correct it, as it currently reads that

$$0 \leq x \leq 0$$

For the second example, to get $\theta $ from $y \geq -x $ draw the line for $y = -x $ and notice that the two "halfs" make angles of $-\frac\pi4$ and $\frac{3\pi}{4} $.

Make a sketch and it'll become fairly obvious that

$$-\frac\pi4 \leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{4} $$

As for the 1st example, consider this sketch:

[image]

From $0 \leq y $ I painted the red region. From $0 \leq x \leq 2$ I painted the blue region and from $x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$ I painted the green quarter of circle. From that you get

$$0 \leq \theta \leq \frac\pi2$$

Comment: @user376343 corrected

Comment: I updated the question. As you said I drew the coordinates for the 1st question and got a circle with radius $2$ but I cannot get the angles. Can you please explain with the picture.

Comment: @user982787 updated my answer with a coloured sketch. Hope it helps

Comment: Since, it is in the first quadrant we have take the angle from $0$ to $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ right

Comment: @user982787 yes indeed, that is the rationale behind the right answer

Comment: can you also please give an answer to this post of mine. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2974178/how-to-evaluate-the-integrals-in-the-cylindrical-coordinates

Comment: @user982787 yeah sure, just give me a couple of minutes